# How to change the font used in text highlighted with soul's package \hl{} command

Tags: fonts, soul

I'm using LaTeX with soul's package `\hl{text}` command to highlight text.

I'd like to know if it is possible to automatically change the font used in text marked with `hl{text}`. I know that I can do this by using `\hl{\texttt{text}}` but I'd like to do not have to type `\hl{\texttt{text}}`, only `hl{text}` and have the font switched to `\texttt`.

I'm new to LaTeX and I have been searching for hours (Google, Soul's docs, etc...) for a solution for this without finding any.

Thanks.

Comment: your question is not very clear, `\hl` does not change the font, you just get the font you would have without the `\hl` command.

Comment: if you really want a command that does hl and texttt use `\newcommand\tthl[1]{\hl{\texttt{#1}}}`  then use `\tthl{...}`

Comment: That's my point. I have read the docs for soul I didn't find and/or understand what I read on how to change it (the default font used in highlighted text I mean).

Comment: `\hl` is is not a font related command, you would not expect to see fonts mentioned in the doc, but see previous comment.

Comment: I understand. But is there a way for all text already marked with `\hl{text}` to be printed with a different font from the rest of the document? Without having to change all places where there is a `hl{text}` with `hl{\texttt{text}}`?

Comment: there is but it would be best to use your editor to change `\hl` to `\tthl` then define `\tthl` as above

Comment: Thanks worked like a charm! This way in the future if I want to change the format of my highlighted text I just need to change the definition of `tthl`. If posted as an answer I would have it voted as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you really want a command that does `\hl` and `\texttt` use

```
  \newcommand\tthl[1]{\hl{\texttt{#1}}}
```

then use `\tthl{...}`